# Airflow on wing, simple force analysis

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, fluid-dynamics, flow, aircraft

**(Look at the picture)**

Let's assume there is an horizontal plane impacted by diagonal airflow with components from coming downwards and ahead. If we say that the airflow is fully deviated by the horizontal window (which isn't allowed to move through space), the outcoming airflow has only an horizontal component greater than the one it had before. So, if the wing generated a force in order to change airflow direction, the airflow generated an opposite force on the wing.

According to this theory as long as the horizontal component of the airflow isn't reduced, the wing is pushed both upwards and forewards, even though the airflow comes from ahead (which is counterintuitive).
Is that correct or am I missing something, since I would normally think the wing must be pushed backwards?
[image: Forces]

Comment: but if that's true then why would we need engines at all ?

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm asking :-)